# How to split multiple items from array and add them into another array in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

if i have an array:

```
input_array = np.array([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l , m, n , o, p, q, r, s, t, u, w, x, y])
```

How to split them into seperate arrays of 5 alphabets where result is:

array1 = [a, b, c, d, e]

array2 = [f, g, h, i, j]

etc

Comment: There is 24 items, so the result cannot be evenly divided.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: yes, you are missing v for there to be a 25 elements.  That said, I think what you are looking for is `input_array = input_array.reshape((5, 5))` because you are working with an numpy array, then every increment of 5 items will be on it's own row (but not assigned to a different variable), that would be just one more step to accomplish.

Comment: basically i have a a 189 element array and i want to seperate it to 21 arrays each of with 9 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [np.array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split):

```py
number_of_splits = 5
array_list = np.array_split(input_array, number_of_splits)
```

If you want to set the variable name for each of those arrays. But depending on your use case, you may end up with spaghetti code if you are unsure of what you are doing.

```py
for i, array in enumerate(array_list):
    variable_name = "array%d" % i
    locals()[variable_name] = array # create local variable array1 = array
# Now you can access array0, array1, array2 ...
```

Comment: basically i have a a 189 element array and i want to seperate it to 21 arrays each of with 9 elements, i didnt know how to ask the question sorry!

Comment: So just use number_of_splits = 21, you will get 21 arrays. Doesn't it work?

Comment: is there a way to set a variable to every one of the arrays tho

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer to set variables names too, but beware of the spaghetti code you are doing with those variables.